# Why isnt the sum of the results of random trials based on a random variable the same as the expected value of the random variable time the # of trials

Tags: probability, summation, absolute-convergence

If $X$ is a random variable and $X_i$ the ith result of an experiment whose underlying probability distribution is $X$ then by the law of large numbers

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i}{n} = \overline{X}.$$

I would therefore expect

$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n \times \overline{X} \rightarrow 0.$$

If I attempt to do this numerically, this is not what I find. In fact, it does not seem that the sum converges at all. Why does this sum not converge?

The code I've used to test this is below (in Python)

```
from random import randint

sum = 0

for i in range(1, 1000):
    sum = sum + randint(1, 100)
    print("{}: {}".format(i, sum-i*50.5))
```

Comment: The sample mean ought to be $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {X_i}n$.  unless $\overline X=0$, your sum certainly looks divergent.

Comment: Indeed, I've fixed this, thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to expect that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n \overline X \to 0.$$
Consider that, say,
$$\frac{n+1}{n} \to 1$$
as $n \to \infty$, but
$$(n + 1) - n \cdot 1 = 1 \not\to 0.$$
These are nonrandom sequences, but I think they illustrate the conceptual mistake.

To go into a little more detail, let $X_1, X_2, \dotsc$ be i.i.d. random variables with mean $\mu$ (i prefer this over $\overline X$ to avoid confusion with the *sample* mean) and standard deviation $\sigma$. Then a quick calculation shows that
$$\text{Var} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n \mu \right) = n \sigma^2,$$
so that the standard deviation of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n \mu$ is $\sqrt n \sigma$. This tells you that the standard deviation of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - n \mu$ *increases* with $n$. On the other hand, if we divide everything by $n$, we get something with standard deviation $\sigma / \sqrt n$, i.e. something whose standard deviation *decreases* with $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that the law of large numbers is about [probabilistic convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) (so your first paragraph is not quite right). Taking the particular case $\overline{X}=0$: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n}=0$$ does *not* imply that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n=0$$

Counterxample: $S_n = \sqrt{n}$